# Using hyperlink with querystring for gridview row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, query-string

Is there someway to turn the row of a gridview into a hyperlink so that when a user opens it in a new tab for example, it goes to that link? Right now I am using a LinkButton and when the user opens it in a new tab, it doesn't know where to go.

I figured the .aspx code would look something like:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>              
                    <Hyperlink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" ForeColor="red" HtmlEncode="false" navigationURL="testUrl.aspx"                             
                </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

The only thing is, our URLs are set up in the C# code behind as a query string, so I'm not sure how to pass that into the navigationURL section.

I'm guessing there's something I can do on the page_load with the query string to redirect to the page I need, but this is my first time working with query strings so I'm a little confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate> 
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/controller.aspx?routeID1={0}&routeID2={1}", Eval("routeid1"), Eval("routeid2"))%>'></asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

**routeid1 and routeid2 are passed as query strings to the controller of that page.**

Comment: So I tried this and I think I figured out how to set the NavigateURL but....my hyperlinks aren't clickable. Did you have that problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I did recently is modified my class to have a readonly property that constructs the A tag for me. This way I have control over what gets displayed; just text or a link.

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="ColumnItem_Title" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DownloadATag") %>'>  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The code behind just binds an instance of the class to the gridview.  You can bind the gridview whenever, on load on postback event, etc.

```
 Dim docs As DocViewList = GetViewList()

 GridViewDocuments.DataSource = docs
 GridViewDocuments.DataBind()
```

In the above code, the DocViewList, instantiated as docs, is a list of a class that has all the properties that are needed to fill my GridView, which is named GridViewDocuments here. Once you set the DataSource of your GridView, you can bind any of the source's properties to an item.

Comment: What does your code behind look like for that Bind("downloadtag") to take you to where you need to go?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Title" runat="server" target="_blank" 
   PostBackUrl='<%# Eval(Request.QueryString["title"]) %>'`

or binding them from the RowCreated event:

```
protected void GridView_OnRowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      (e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton_Title") as LinkButton).PostBackUrl = Request.QueryString["title"]))
    }
}
```